# Freshdesk backfill sync into Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql, azure, synchronization, replication, freshdesk

What are the best methods for Syncing data from Freshdesk to Azure SQL Server?

I have tried methods such as Logic Apps, FiveTran, Rubber Stack, Automate.io, and Skyvia (Which worked for getting the data in but had rate limit issues).

I am open to any recommendations for pulling the historical data into SQL server from Freshdesk.
I am not looking for options to update tickets or syncing new tickets only a replication of the entire ticket table if possible.

Thank you!